How can i convert python project into exe file with directory
I made python project for my university. It is kinda big, has stockfish in its content
How can i make an exe game?
I tried auto-to-py exe and it didt work (maybe because of this PyTask_chess/PyTask/chess)
How can i convert this into exe file

"it didt work" doesn't help us help you. What happened that shouldn't have, what didn't happen that should have? Also, we don't know what PyTask_chess/PyTask/chess is and how it might affect things.

PyInstaller can bundle your files into one package and users can run it without installing python.
